# The controller for path '/Admin/Widget/ConfigureWidget' was not found or does not implement IController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, nopcommerce

I have a Nopcommerce 3.30 (with source code) project and I have configured my own Widget plugin. When I have install it and I'm trying to configure it in '../Admin/Widget/List', the following error Appears:

> The controller for path '/Admin/Widget/ConfigureWidget' was not found
>   or does not implement IController.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The controller for path
>   '/Admin/Widget/ConfigureWidget' was not found or does not implement
>   IController.

Source Error:

```
Line 12: @if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.ConfigurationActionName))
Line 13: {
Line 14:     @Html.Action(Model.ConfigurationActionName, Model.ConfigurationControllerName, Model.ConfigurationRouteValues);
Line 15: }
Line 16: else
```

Plugin controller:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Caching;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.ApplicationNotes.Infrastructure.Cache;
using Nop.Plugin.Widgets.ApplicationNotes.Models;
using Nop.Services.Configuration;
using Nop.Services.Media;
using Nop.Services.Stores;
using Nop.Web.Framework.Controllers;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.ApplicationNotes.Controllers
{
    class WidgetsApplicationNotesController : BasePluginController
    {

                private readonly IWorkContext _workContext;
        private readonly IStoreContext _storeContext;
        private readonly IStoreService _storeService;
        private readonly IPictureService _pictureService;
        private readonly ISettingService _settingService;
        private readonly ICacheManager _cacheManager;

        public WidgetsApplicationNotesController(IWorkContext workContext,
            IStoreContext storeContext,
            IStoreService storeService, 
            IPictureService pictureService,
            ISettingService settingService,
            ICacheManager cacheManager)
        {
            this._workContext = workContext;
            this._storeContext = storeContext;
            this._storeService = storeService;
            this._pictureService = pictureService;
            this._settingService = settingService;
            this._cacheManager = cacheManager;
        }
```

This is my plugin class

```
using Nop.Core;
using Nop.Core.Plugins;
using Nop.Services.Cms;
using Nop.Services.Configuration;
using Nop.Services.Localization;
using Nop.Services.Media;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Nop.Plugin.Widgets.ApplicationNotes
{
    public class ApplicationNotesPlugin: BasePlugin, IWidgetPlugin
    {

        private readonly IPictureService _pictureService;
        private readonly ISettingService _settingService;
        private readonly IWebHelper _webHelper;

        public ApplicationNotesPlugin(IPictureService pictureService, 
            ISettingService settingService, IWebHelper webHelper)
        {
            this._pictureService = pictureService;
            this._settingService = settingService;
            this._webHelper = webHelper;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets widget zones where this widget should be rendered
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Widget zones</returns>
        public IList<string> GetWidgetZones()
        {
            return new List<string>() { "home_page_top" };
        }
```

I don't understand what's the source of the error.
Thanks

Comment: can you give me controller code with controller main method means public basecontroller

Comment: please give me your controller details like this "public class HomeController"

Comment: This is the controller of my plugin if you refer to plugin controller.

Comment: yes i want it's full detail so can you provice just public class yourcontroller : basecontroller

Comment: ok, can I provide you with more usefull information?

Comment: ok now also inherit your controller with Iwidget too

Comment: YOu need to inherit your controller with Iwidget too, then your issue will solve

Comment: i hope this helps you if not work then tell me

Comment: It still don't work. My plugin main class inherits from IWidgetPlugin

Comment: try to use ImisePlugin too it's works...

Comment: What is ImisePlugin?

Comment: There is any idea to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't realized that my controller was not public:

```
class WidgetsApplicationNotesController : BasePluginController
```

Comment: This simple answer fixed my issue after 1 long day of debugging!